# How to check emulator or rooted device?

Tags: android, emulation

I have used rootBeer and rootBeerFresh libraries in my application but none of them is able to detect bluestack device. My application smoothly running on every emulator and root device. Seems like they are not working now.

I have also tried fetching BUILD vars but today emulator doesn't have weird value to make them distinct.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: You could try checking for write permissions on `/data/data`, if you get write permission on that folder you're probably on a rooted device. As for bluestacks, I guess checking for the device vendor maybe?

Comment: Let me check this out.